# C++ regex library with substitution to function pointer

Tags: c++, python, regex, function-pointers

Looking for something similar to Python's regex `sub` or `subn` methods.

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

So basically a C/C++ api like this

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Where I can put a function pointer for `repl` like you can in Python.

Comment: Have a look at [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   std::string text = "Quick brown fox";
   std::regex vowel_re("a|o|e|u|i");
   std::cout << std::regex_replace(text, vowel_re, "[$&]") << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Q[u][i]ck br[o]wn f[o]x
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vikas is correct (at least I'm pretty sure he is) that `std::regex_replace` can do what you want, but he doesn't really show how to do that. When you use `regex_replace`, each match of the regex produces a `regex::match` object. That object's `format` member function is invoked with the replacement string you pass to `regex_replace` (and the flags you pass).

So, to get the same effect as you're talking about in Python (invoking a function for each replacement, instead of just specifying replacement text) you have to create a `regex::match` object that overloads its `format` member function, and that's the function that will get invoked. By default, the standard `regex::match::format` can do either ECMAScript/Javascript replacement or `sed` replacement (you can pass a flag to signal which you prefer).

I should add, however, that actually doing this seems fairly unusual -- although the standard makes it pretty clear that it's possible, I don't know of any book on the subject that demonstrates how to do it.